# The Correlation between Complex Function Integral and Analyticity

Tags: complex-analysis

The integral of a complex function along any circle is zero. What does it mean? What interesting results can be derived?
For example,there is a question about that:
If f(z) resolves within 0<|z|<1 and the integral along any circle |z|=r(r<1) is equal to zero, then does f(z) resolve at |z|=0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the integral along any path is zero of a continuous function, then we can construct a global (holomorphic) primitive of this function. Since the derivative of a holomorphic function is holomorphic, the function we started with is also holomorphic.

Comment: Get it.Thank you!

Comment: @Coisini If the answer suffices you should mark it accordingly.